# Powershell script to sum up each character in a string

Tags: string, parsing, powershell, character

Looking for a way to sum up all unique characters in a string, so if the string is:

```
!#*@&$&$&@^$*%(%&#
```

The script would output

```
1 ! found

2 # found

2 * found

2 @ found

4 & found

3 $ found

1 ^ found
```

etc..

I found a lot of ways to manipulate strings, but not this. Any help would rule!
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Break the string into separate characters and group them:

```
PS> '!#@&$&$&@^$%(%&#'.ToCharArray() | Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending

Count Name
----- ----
    4 &
    3 $
    2 #
    2 @
    2 %
    1 !
    1 ^
    1 (
```

If you save the result to a variable, you can later get the first item ( most frequent character) using array indexing (thanks @JNK).

```
PS>  $chars = '!#@&$&$&@^$%(%&#'.ToCharArray() | Group-Object ...   
PS>  $chars[0]

Count Name
----- ----
    4 &
```

Comment: Nice!  The OP should know he can wrap that line in parentheses and treat it like an array if he wants to do things like index into it or pull back the values to put into a string.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, String indexing is another option but IMO is less preferred since you need to know the length of the string, create a for loop, iterate over all characters sum the characters on your own.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean string indexing.  I meant if he wants to know what the most frequent character is he can wrap your line in parentheses and index to `[0]`, to treat it like an array or collection.